# detecting errors and solution for it- Xcode 4.2 - Instrument [Memory Leaks]

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, xcode4.2, xcode-instruments

According to stack-over flow guidance I did my memory management things. SO I discovered memory leaks. thanks for all about it. Now how could I find memory allocation that I didn't **release** ?

Is their any easy way to do it on instrument on Xcode. I attached my memory leaks image below.

[image]

SO is their any easy way to catch that *3 leaks* [mention on resulted image] from is tool ?

Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the leaks row inside of the time line (where the red bars
   are) click on them, dont double click them.
2. This will display in Object Summary which items where leaked.
3. Next display the far right panel, (see the button that isn't clicked
   in view)
4. Single click an item in the Object Summary it will display a stack
   trace on the item that was leaked.
5. Look through the the stack trace double click on the highest item from your project
6. This will open and highlight where the leak has occurred

Comment: Hi,

I uploaded real image now. I think your are talking about stack trace panel. So how could I do this ?

Comment: In Responsible Library All the ones with VakaruApp are caused by the your app

Comment: Click on those and they will bring up the stack trace, double click the line (closest to the top, in stack trace) that is the darker of two colours.

See the -[PackageList connection:didReceive....

Any code within your project should look like that text in the stack trace, most of these are probably from not releasing.

Comment: When you double click it will bring you to the offending variable/line. Keep in mind the code might be correct, but you prob forgot the release them